# Linux virtual machine keeps crashing/freezing

Tags: keyboard, mac

When I use Linux (running gazebo and PID tuning) the screen keeps freezing and showing numbers over the applications on the side.

[image: image of this attached]

I am running this on a 2019 Intel MacBook.
I at first thought I had maybe run a shortcut accidentally, but I cannot get out of this state unless I completely restart the virtual machine.
One time the keyboard shortcuts page came up with the numbers, however, I could not get out of that either.

[image: image of this attached]

Comment: The numbers appear when holding down the ALT key. It's just an aide to help you switch applications via ALT+1, ALT+2 etc.

Comment: @popey thank you for your comment but I still can't seem to get out of the application menu no matter what I press. It seems the VM has crashed